# JetBrains Rider - Pytest 'chromedriver must be in Path' from IDE configuration only

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, jetbrains-ide

I recently upgraded to macOS 12 Monterey and my run configuration for python seems to have borked and I cannot seem to find the right magic buttons. It has been working fine until the upgrade.
I have a run configuration that runs `pytest <test-path>`

When I run it I get this exception

```
if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
>               raise WebDriverException(
                   "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
                       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
E                       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:81: WebDriverException
```

if I run `pytest <test-path>` from the terminal, works like a dream. I am running from a virtual env, but if I `which chromedriver` from the venv or not, I see the directory - I can run `chromedriver` by name in venv or not.

```
(venv) me ~/Documents/project(main)* $ which python3
/Users/me/project/venv/bin/python3
```

the run configuration in Rider is pointed to this same python interpreter

What gives, where is `$PATH` getting lost in this mix?

Comment: I'd start by double checking if Rider is running the same shell. macOS has been changing the default shell from bash to zsh for a while, so if you're using bash in your terminal and your $PATH is being set in your .bashrc, then zsh won't pick it up.

Comment: from terminal
`echo $0; /bin/bash`
that's the one set in rider preferences

Comment: that's a good call out though, I see at the bottom of my `~/.bash_profile` a patch for python 3.9 path `# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH`

Comment: I tried a before launch shell script (that sets the path above) but it seems really unlikely that the two steps would share the shell - it didn't work